# Microscopy particle size

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

Hi I try to detect the particle length size from this image[image]

and I'd like to get the length size of the particle Like this below. and get the histogram of the size of the particle

[image]

First I threshold and draw the contour. And what I get is like this...I have try so many way to threshold but the particle which is unite with the other material is false the reading. I try to watershed but its seems failed. I try to using Kmeans and watershed the K Means but I don't know how to do it. Are there any suggestion what I should to do to get the particle size..
[image]

Here it is my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
import scalar
import sys
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import filters
from sklearn import cluster
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy.ndimage import label

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\adiyu\Pictures\\snipping\\c3smeasure.png", 
cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],[-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
kernel2 = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

img=cv2.filter2D(img,-255, kernel)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,3)
img_np = np.array(img)
img_np_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_np,cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)


#Kmeans cluster using Opencv
Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 3
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)
# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)


res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))
gray= cv2.cvtColor(res2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, 6,7,21)


cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + 
cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
cv2.imshow("opening", opening)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel2, iterations=2)
cv2.imshow("closing", closing)

fg = cv2.erode(closing,None,iterations = 2)
cv2.imshow("fg", fg)

bgt = cv2.dilate(closing,None,iterations = 3)
ret,bg = cv2.threshold(bgt,1,128,1)
cv2.imshow("bg", bg)
marker = cv2.add(fg,bg)
cv2.imshow("marker", marker)

#Then we convert it into 32SC1 :
marker32 = np.int32(marker)

# Finally we apply watershed and convert result back into uint8 image:
cv2.watershed(img,marker32)
m = cv2.convertScaleAbs(marker32)
cv2.imshow("m", m)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(m,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = thresh)
cv2.imshow("res", res)
#plt.figure(figsize=(35,35) 
#plt.imshow(cv2.morphologyEx(img_np_rgb,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,np.ones((2,2))
,iterations=10))
#model = cluster.KMeans(3)
#plt.figure(figsize=35,35))
#aa=model.fit_predict(img_np_rgb.reshape((-1,3)))
.reshape(img_np_rgb.shape[:2])

#plt.imshow(gray)
#plt.show()

#-------Draw Contour------
c, h= cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for i in c:
    area = cv2.contourArea(i)
    if area > 10:
    epsilon = 0.00001*cv2.arcLength(i, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i, epsilon, True)
    img2 =cv2.drawContours(img,[approx], -1, (0,255,0), 2)


cv2.imshow("img2", img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try out a distance-transformation before applying your WST.